# css3 rotated ul dissapears in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, rotation, html-lists

**Hello people!**

I'm having a problem arround css3 rotation in IE...

I have an unordered list that is rotated in -90deg because my customers' design needs it. In Chrome and Firefox it show well but in IE after I move the mouse the whole UL will get lost.

I've made a fiddle for this case and would ask you to take a look for it. I just cant find what's the problem about it.

The UL is in absolute position ( if not absolute it won't be rotated ) and there's a div with topline but it no matters. I'm using css grid (generated on 960.gs) and a css master reset for my site and the HTML5 sticky footer.

On this [example](http://goo.gl/naAkd) you can check out. If anyone has idea on solving this problem please tell me...

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: It works just fine in my Internet Explorer? (IE10)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:
[CSS3 Transform to Matrix filter converter](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/index.html)

This will give you the code needed to render what you are looking for in IE.